# How to store HDFC payment gateway response data value in database

Tags: php, payment-gateway

Hello I am implementing HDFC new payment gateway in php. All things working well. But in response i am getting datastring like:

> txn_status=0300|txn_msg=success|txn_err_msg=NA|clnt_txn_ref=000000|tpsl_bank_cd=000000|tpsl_txn_id=000000|txn_amt=1.00|clnt_rqst_meta={itc:NIC~TXN0001~122333~rt14154~8
>   mar 2014~Payment~forpayment}{custname:test}|tpsl_txn_time=15-02-2016
>   11:44:41|tpsl_rfnd_id=NA|bal_amt=NA|rqst_token=000000-205b-4253-bbb8-0e9976e22147|hash=0000000000000000000

From above datastring i want to get particular value to store in database.

**For example**:

I want to store txn_msg, date time, transaction id etc into database. How can i get it ?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad, please edit to show us what have you tried and a piece of code where we can work on

Comment: hello sir, i just want to get particular element from above datastring.

Comment: Probably best to use a regex (*something like `(?:txn_msg\=)(\w+)\|` is a start*) or harness php's inbuilt [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your string in two steps:

```
$values = explode("|", $yourstring);
foreach($values as $val) {
    $keyval = explode("=", $val);
    $ass_array[$keyval[0]] = $keyval[1];
}
```

With this you'll have an associative array containing your data like this:

```
"txn_status" => "0300",
"txn_msg" => "success",
and so on...
```

Then you can store the data in your database as you whish.